# If-else then do in SAS

Tags: sas

Hi I would like to know the steps of a multiple if then condition.

I would like to do the following:

```
data _ ;
set _ ;
if condition 1 is true then do; 
if sub condition 1 is true then _ ;
else if sub condition2 is true then _;
else if ... ;
end;
else if condition 2 is true then do; /* Is it right? */
if sub condition 1 is true then _ ;
else if sub condition2 is true then _;
else if ... ;
end;
run;
```

Could you please tell me which the right steps are? I should include else if or else do?

For example: condition 1 can take values 1 or 0. sub-conditions (I will call them as test1,test2, test3, ...) are other conditions. So I would have something like :

```
data _ ;
set _ ;
if condition1 = 1 then do;
if test1 = . then test3=test2; else test3=test1; 
else if test1 = 'My test' or test2= 'My test' then test3=test2 else test3=test2; 
end; 
else if condition1=0 then do;
if test1 = . then test3=test2; else test3=test1; 
else if test1 = 'My test' or test2= 'My test' then test3=test2 else test3=test2; 
end; 
else test3=test2;
run;
```

A sample of data could be:

```
condition1   test1        test2
1             .            M
0             My test      .
1             Love        home
0             Home         .
```

what I would like to select is, based on condition1 values,

if condition1 is 1 and test1 is . then assign to test3 test2's value, otherwise test3=test1; and so on.

My expected output would be then:

```
condition1   test1        test2       test3
1             .            M           M
0             My test      .           My test
1             Love        home         Love
0             Home         .           Home
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what the question is.  The DO/END block is just so you can replace a single statement with multiple statements.

Comment: In your example is the variable TEST1 numeric or character?  In some places you are treating it as numeric, `test1 = .`, and in other places as character, `test1 = 'My test'`.  You can use the `missing()` function to test if a variable is missing and it will work the same for numeric or character variables, plus it will detect special missing values like `.A`, `.Z` etc.

Comment: In a dataset I have found . and NA values (the latter as string). Is there any way to check the type of the variable?

Comment: PROC CONTENTS will show you information about a dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking, but perhaps this will help you.

You can think of the nested ifs as additional conditions.  So if you had

```
if test1 then do;
  if test2 then statement1 ;
  else if test3 then statement2 ;
end;
```

You could re-write it as

```
if test1 and test2 then statement1 ;
else if test1 and test3 then statement2 ;
```

Comment: Thank you Tom. So the same approach would be good with then do? There are two different conditions (for example condition1 = 1 and condition2 is the other value of condition1 if binary, i.e. 0). Then I consider sub-conditions (yours test2 and test3). The problem is the logic. I have not a dataset but something in mind that probably could suit as an example, if you like

Comment: I included a possible example in my question. Thanks for your help

Comment: To see if the two methods are the same consider every possible value for the test conditions.  So if you have two tests you are making there are 4 possible combinations, FF, FT, TF, and TT.  Consider each and check if both programs yield the same results. For N tests there are 2**N possible combinations.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I will check it and let you know